# C# ListView Vertical Scroll

Tags: c#, listview, scrollbar

I have been using a Winform ListView in my project. When the list view (items arranged in list) exceeds the window space it starts a new list on the right and creates a horizontal scroll bar, I need it to carry on the list below and the scroll bar to be vertical. I have mananged to do this using the suggestions from a similar Stack Overflow question but it creates columns, which I don't want, unless there is a way to hide this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start by reading this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx

The list view behaves in rather different ways depending on the setting of the `View` property. Microsoft have explained it fairly well.

Comment: In case it is relevant to anyone else I found this code which works - listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
ColumnHeader h = new ColumnHeader();
h.Width = listView1.ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
listView1.Columns.Add(h); This will create a hidden column in a ListView with the arrangement being List not details, and will create a vertical scroll bar

Comment: Following on from @BaliC's comment, you can set the `ColumnHeader`'s `Width` property to `-1` to have it auto-size (once) to the column's content. Although, you will need to set it to this value every time the items are modified in order to have the header adjust its width accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

The *SmallIcon* view might be more suitable to you since it looks pretty much like the *List*, instead of the items are oriented vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This is a derivative of this answer, but changed a little

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309205/22097795

If anyone is still looking for this

```
ListView1.View = View.Details;
ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
header.Text = "";
header.Name = "dummy";
header.Width = 100;
ListView1.Columns.Add(header);
ListView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
```

The 100 in the Width is the width of the Control so if that is dynamic you will need to change it